# Retrieving the contents of an html label using XPath

Tags: java, html, xpath

I have the following html code:

```
<div id="ipsLayout_contentArea">
<div class="preContentPadding">
<div id="ipsLayout_contentWrapper">
<div id="ipsLayout_mainArea">
<a id="elContent"></a>
<div class="cWidgetContainer " data-widgetarea="header" data-orientation="horizontal" data-role="widgetReceiver" data-controller="core.front.widgets.area">
<div class="ipsPageHeader ipsClearfix">
<div class="ipsClearfix">
<div class="cTopic ipsClear ipsSpacer_top" data-feedid="topic-100269" data-lastpage="" data-baseurl="https://forum.com/forum/topic/100269-topic/" data-autopoll="" data-controller="core.front.core.commentFeed,forums.front.topic.view">
<div class="" data-controller="core.front.core.moderation" data-role="commentFeed">
<form data-role="moderationTools" data-ipspageaction="" method="post" action="https://forum.com/forum/topic/100269-topic/?csrfKey=b092dccccee08fdbc06c26d350bf3c2b&do=multimodComment">
<a id="comment-626016"></a>
<article id="elComment_626016" class="cPost ipsBox ipsComment ipsComment_parent ipsClearfix ipsClear ipsColumns ipsColumns_noSpacing ipsColumns_collapsePhone " itemtype="http://schema.org/Comment" itemscope="">
<aside class="ipsComment_author cAuthorPane ipsColumn ipsColumn_medium">
<div class="ipsColumn ipsColumn_fluid">
<div id="comment-626016_wrap" class="ipsComment_content ipsType_medium ipsFaded_withHover" data-quotedata="{"userid":3859,"username":"Admin","timestamp":1453221383,"contentapp":"forums","contenttype":"forums","contentid":100269,"contentclass":"forums_Topic","contentcommentid":626016}" data-commentid="626016" data-commenttype="forums" data-commentapp="forums" data-controller="core.front.core.comment">
<div class="ipsComment_meta ipsType_light">
<div class="cPost_contentWrap ipsPad">
<div class="ipsType_normal ipsType_richText ipsContained" data-controller="core.front.core.lightboxedImages" itemprop="text" data-role="commentContent">
<p> Hi, </p>
<p>   </p>
<p> This is a post with multiple </p>
<p> lines of text </p>
```

and am trying to get the contents (in plaintext) of the post. The XPath I'm currently using:

```
//div[@id='ipsLayout_contentArea']/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/form/article/div/div/div[2]/div//text()
```

retrieves each line of each post (as delimited by `<p></p>`). How can I get the whole contents of the post (inside:

```
<div class="ipsType_normal ipsType_richText ipsContained" data-controller="core.front.core.lightboxedImages" itemprop="text" data-role="commentContent"> Post content </div>),
```

in plaintext (so that `<p></p>` is treated as a text (as well as other labels that the post might include))?

**Edit:**

I'm using the following XPath:

```
//div[@id='ipsLayout_contentArea']/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/form/article/div/div/div[2]/div
```

to retrieve the div that contains the body of the post.

```
// forumTemplate.getXpathElements().get(forumTemplate.XPATH_GET_THREAD_POSTS) = //div[@id='ipsLayout_contentArea']/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/form/article/div/div/div[2]/div
List<DomNode> posts = (List<DomNode>) firstPage.getByXPath(forumTemplate.getXpathElements().get(forumTemplate.XPATH_GET_THREAD_POSTS));
                for (DomNode post : posts) {
                    // Retrieve the contents of the post as a string
                    String postContentStr = post.getNodeValue();
```

The variable `postContentStr` is always null. Why?

Comment: That can't be done in XPath only. Get your XPath to select the `div` and get content of the `div` as text from java (can't help with the java part though)

Comment: I can get the div as a dom node but am unable to get its value (all labels bellow it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specified `//text()`, that will get all text nodes under the specified path recursively. Depending of what you use, this could work better:

```
//div[@data-role='commentContent']
```

That will match the comment node you are trying to get. If you use code to evaluate, you can go from here. Don't match `text()` though, that will not match any of the `<p>` tags.

Comment: I don't want it rendered, just its contents in plaintext (with all labels it might contain read as text, a String in Java). The document is an html page not an xml.

Comment: It is html, but it is also xml as you process it with xpath and build a dom tree. So, as far as I can see, you are building a DOM tree out of the HTML, then match a specific Node in this DOM. Now, you are trying to *render* the DOM sub-tree back to HTML. The point is, XPath does not work on "text" level, although I understand that is what you ultimately would like.